# setting ViewPaths of telerik RadFileExplorer in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

how can i set the ViewPaths of RadFileExplorer to the root of the pc. ie i have 2 drives (c and d) and i want to view both of them in the RadFileExplorer.
to what value should i set the ViewPaths ??

Answer (score 1):

The file explorer only works with the folders in the web application by default - you cannot set a physical path directly, only application relative paths (i.e. starting with ~/).

If you want to use a physical path, you need to use a different content provider for the RadFileExplorer control. See http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/physical-paths-and-different-content-types.aspx for more information.